# Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, stability-in-odes

This question derived from after I reading the book **Naive Lie Theory**, by Jhon Stillwell .

For the CBH thoerem, I am wondering how to construct some example about **Exponential of Matrix**, which has some property like :
$$F_1(X,Y)=X+Y, F_2=\frac{1}{2}[X,Y],F_k[X,Y]=0,\forall k\geq 3$$
where $F_i(X,Y)$ comes from :
$$e^Xe^Y=e^Z,Z=F_1(X,Y)+F_2(X,Y)+...$$
And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638627/expab-and-baker-campbell-hausdorff), the answer 1, give a example for scalar matrix, but I wonder if we can construct a function matrix (suppose a function matrix respect to variable $t$)  also satisfying my require.

In deed, my question comes from the existence and uniqueness of solution of linear ODEs.

Any hints and help we be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: One example is the set  $X=x$ and  $Y=p=-id/(dx)$, the position and momentum operators acting in ${L^2}(R)$. Then ${F_2}=i/2$ and the higher ones vanish.

Answer (score 0):

According to BCH, if $[X,Y]$ commute with $X$ and $Y$, then $\exp(X)\exp(Y)=\exp(X+Y+1/2[X,Y])$.

Comment: This is trivial. I want some example $[X,Y]\neq 0$, i.e. $X$ and $Y$ don't commute.

Comment: It is not. You did not understand my post.Reread it.  Anyway, there are not other known examples.